# Trouble when declaring a range (for getting values from merged cells)

Tags: vba, excel, merge, range

I am trying to get the values from merged cells (which are at the offset of a .find gcell result) through a loop that goes through rows one by one (and looks for specific values on an other sheet) .This code goes if the cell we are looking for is merged and does the following:

-Unmerges
-Gets the limits of the merged cells by the use of .Address
-looks for the value contained in these cells
-re-writes the value over them

At this point it doesn't work and I believe because of variable format as .address gives a string and the property rows.value and .MergeArea needs a range My question is, How can I change from an Address string to a range? Maybe like this I can fix this.
If you have any other siggestion I'll be glad to listen.

Thank you very much.

Code:

(LOOP CODE NOT DISPLAYED AS IT WORKS WELL)

```
lineasemergidasCont = gCell.Offset(, 4).MergeArea.Rows.count
                      emergidainicio = gCell.Offset(, 4).Address
                      emergidafinal = gCell.Offset(lineasemergidasCont, 4).Address
  goes well until here------->  Range(emergidainicio, emergidafinal).MergeArea.UnMerge
                                 filainicio = emergidainicio.Rows.Value
                                  filafinal = emergidafinal.Rows.Value
                                       For p = filainicio To filafinal
                                            If  .Cells(p, 10).Value <> "" Then
                                                 .Cells(p, 10).Value = datoemergido
                                            End If
                                       Next p
                                        For s = filainicio To filafinal
                                            datoemergido = .Cells(s, 10).Value
                                       Next s
```

(CODE CONTINUES EFFICENTLY)

Comment: What exactly does "doesn't work" mean? You can certainly pass two address strings to a Range call.

Comment: I did not know how but it did not pass. How could I do that? It's my code right? I've tried like set sheets(...).range("address") but when I did an inmediate call on emergidainicio or emergidafinal they were empty

Comment: If you want to Unmerge a Merged range its enough to just Pick one cell in the merged area and call .Unmerge - e.g. Range(emergidainicio).Unmerge

Comment: Agree with @therak or more like `gCell.Offset(, 4).Unmerge`.

Comment: you cannot have a mergearea of 2 ranges at once. make it in two lines for `Range(emergidainicio).MergeArea.UnMerge` and then the other...

Answer (score 0):

@rory, @patrick lapelletier, @therak,Thank you ALL! Here I drop the code that finally works to:

-find merged cells
-unmerge these
-copy the found value on one of them and post it to all the merged
-take the value to an other sheet

it also takes in account the values that can be duplicated, adding the rest of the results behind the old ones.
this works in a loop with a .find function that gives the result on gcell

```
          do
            If gCell.Offset(, 4).MergeArea.Address = gCell.Offset(, 4).Address Then
                              'Not a merged cell
                          If HojaNueva.Cells(F2, 20).Value = "" Then
                               HojaNueva.Cells(F2, 20).Value = gCell.Offset(, 4).Value
                          Else
                            hojito1 = HojaNueva.Cells(F2, 20).Value
                            HojaNueva.Cells(F2, 20).Value = hojito1 & "," & gCell.Offset(, 4).Value
                           End If

                     Else
                            'is a merged cell
                           lineasemergidasCont = gCell.Offset(, 4).MergeArea.Rows.count
                           emergidainicio = gCell.Offset(, 4).Address
                           emergidafinal = gCell.Offset(lineasemergidasCont - 1, 4).Address
                           Range(emergidainicio).MergeArea.UnMerge
                            Range(emergidafinal).MergeArea.UnMerge
                           numeros1 = Range(emergidainicio).Row
                           numeros2 = Range(emergidafinal).Row

                              For p = numeros1 To numeros2
                                  If Not ws.Cells(p, 10).Value = "" Then
                                     datoemergido = ws.Cells(p, 10).Value
                                   End If
                               Next p
                               For s = numeros1 To numeros2
                                       ws.Cells(s, 10).Value = datoemergido
                                Next s
                                 numeros1 = ""
                                 numeros2 = ""

                                If HojaNueva.Cells(F2, 20).Value = "" Then
                                  HojaNueva.Cells(F2, 20).Value = datoemergido
                                 Else
                                  hojito3 = HojaNueva.Cells(F2, 20).Value
                                  HojaNueva.Cells(F2, 20).Value = hojito3 & "," & datoemergido
                                 End If

                             End If

                           Set gCell = ws.Columns("F").FindNext(gCell)

                          Loop While firstAddress <> gCell.Address
```